Emulator Only Appears in Taskbar and Not on Screen When Launched from VS Code
I’m encountering an issue with the Android Emulator when launching it from Visual Studio Code. The emulator appears in the taskbar but does not display on the screen. The problem does not occur when launching the emulator from Android Studio.enter image description here
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Checked Environment Variables: All relevant paths are correctly set.

Verified Emulator Configuration: The emulator runs fine and connects to my project but doesn’t display properly.

Modified Emulator Window Position: I created or edited the emulator-user.ini file in the AVD directory with window.x and window.y set to positive values (e.g., 100 and 20), but the problem persists.


Emulator Details:

AVD Name: Pixel_8_2_Pro_API_TiramisuPrivacySandbox

Emulator Version: 35.1.20

Windows Version: [Your Windows Version]


Error Log: [Include any relevant log messages or output you have, especially from running the emulator with -verbose]
What I Need Help With:

How can I ensure the emulator opens correctly on the screen when launched from VS Code?

Are there any additional configuration steps or fixes that I might have missed?


Additional Information:

The emulator works fine when launched from Android Studio.

I’ve tried various solutions such as adjusting window position settings and checking environment variables.



I encountered the same issue on Windows 11.
Like you, I selected the Pixel 8 Pro in the emulator and then opened the emulator in VS Code, but it always appeared outside of my screen.
Later, I opened another emulator called "Medium Phone," and I could see the lower half of the emulator. Then I went into the display settings and changed the screen resolution, and the emulator successfully returned to within my screen (though the same method did not work for the Pixel 8 Pro emulator).
In the Medium Phone emulator, I clicked the settings (three dots) in the lower right corner, checked "Emulator always on top," and then returned to the Pixel 8 Pro emulator. Now it consistently appears on the screen.

Install the latest version of Android Studio and update all SDK tools, especially the emulator. It always works for me

it is up to date
i try to up date it
